# Why do we call activity method onDestroy() then onCreate() then onPause() methods when Dialog is to be dismissed?

Tags: android, android-layout

I don't know why do we call activity method `onDestroy()` then `onCreate()` after that `onPause()` methods to dismiss the `Dialog`. 
I don't want to call activity `onDestroy()` when I call `Dialog.dismiss()`.

What is wrong with this?

```
    dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_layout);
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    mCancel = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.cancel);
    mCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.v("log_tag", "Signature Canceled");
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    dialog.show();
```

Here is dialog_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="400dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@android:color/white">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/primaryColor"
    android:text="@string/dialog_title"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:padding="@dimen/layout_padding10"
    android:gravity="center"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="3"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cancel"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/hint_cancel"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:background="@color/primary_color" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/clear"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/hint_clear"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:background="@color/primary_color" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/getsign"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/hint_save"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:background="@color/primary_color" />

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is XML code for reference.

Comment: Can you show the xml relative to r.layout.dialog_layout and the manifest of you app? It seem that the dismiss of your dialog cause an orientation change of the activity, in this case the activity is destroyed and then recreated.

Comment: Please check updated code.

Comment: Hi, There was a recreate() calling so that activity was re created. Thanks all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was recreate() method called in my code so that it was creating activity again.
So I have just removed and got solution.